# visible and hide specific excel sheet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

this is my variables and my input and result excel file are in different workbooks and I want to show the output workbook only. I want to show Targetworkboo1 in output but with this code, sourceworkbook and Targetworkbook1 will be shown in output. how should I do it?

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook SourceWorkbook;
xlApp.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook TargetWorkbook1;
Excel.Worksheet SourceWorksheet;
Excel.Worksheet TargetWorksheet1;
SourceWorksheet = SourceWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
TargetWorkbook1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
TargetWorksheet1 = TargetWorkbook1.Worksheets[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

Hide any sheets in excel workbook using this code:

```
SourceWorksheet.Visible=Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the window of the workbook:

```
SourceWorkbook.Windows[1].Visible = false;
```

Comment: this code only hide the content of excel worksheet but the excel window is open and I do not want to show the sourceWorkbook.